# In stuck with QRegularexpression

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregularexpression

I need to build a regular expression to match the following set of strings :

test, tested, testing

And I have the following test scenario :

```
QRegularExpression re("^[test]{1}[ing|ed]{0,1}", QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption);

QString test = "test";
QVERIFY(re.match(test).hasMatch() == true );

QString test1 = "tested";
QVERIFY(re.match(test1).hasMatch() == true );

QString test2 = "testing";
QVERIFY(re.match(test2).hasMatch() == true );

QString test3 = "teste";
QVERIFY(re.match(test3).hasMatch() == false );
```

test3 is failed and I understand the reason, but how can I fix it? I need to skip 'e' character from matching...

Comment: Use `"^test(?:ing|ed)?"`

Comment: It doesn't work - just tested

Comment: Use a word boundary if you need to match a whole word, `"^test(?:ing|ed)?\\b"`. Still, the main problem here is that you used `[....]` instead of a grouping construct.

Comment: This "^test(?:ing|ed)?\\b" works and this "^test(?:ing|ed{0,1})" does not. What is the meaning of "?:" here? I see that if I remove it this pattern seems to be ok...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do

Comment: Thanks for the link - now everything is clear for me